# Trying to update gantry package, get this error

Tags: joomla

I am following instructions elsewhere to upgrade Joomla from 2.5.x to 2.5.28 in preparation to upgrade to 3.5.

The install, and DB steps went fine. 2 package updates were fine, but when I try to do Gantry to 4.1.33, whether through update or install, it throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method JInstallerPackage::getManifest() in /home1/someuser/public_html/joomlatest/tmp/install_599de020ec6ed/install.php on line 75
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks
JimR

Comment: This question is also asked at: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/21401/120